# Show application short-cut menu instead of jump list

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, if I shift right click a short-cut on the taskbar that is not running I get the standard short-cut menu that includes "Run as Administrator".

However, once the application is running, shift right-clicking only shows the applications menu (eg Restore, Move, Size, etc).

Is there a key combination that will show the standard short-cut menu instead of the applications system menu when the application is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one. Once you launch an application the taskbar shows its window, it no longer shows the shortcut. So you are right-clicking on a window taskbar button.

A solution would be to first right-click the window button and then SHIFT right-click the shortcut in the jump list.